# extracting the json value through json path extractor in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using JSON path extractor with Jmeter.

I need to extract 36735928 or 37851136 which is inside CURRENT. Tried with but no success.

$.payload.reservationLists.CURRENT.[0]

Any suggestion of how to get those values. I don't want to use Regular expression extractor. Is it possible to get the value of the below JSON.

JSON response as below

```
{
"payload": {
            "userName": {
                        "firstName": "Peter",
                         "lastName": "Pan"
                         },
           "reservationLists": {
                            "CURRENT": {
                                      "36735928": {
                                                    "startDate": "2013-10-03",
                                                     "destination": "Balearen",
                                                     "mainProductType": "Mietwagen",
                                                    "allProductTypes": [
                                                                     "Mietwagen"
                                                                       ]
                                                    },
                                      "37851136": {
                                                   "startDate": "2013-10-14",
                                                   "destination": "Nevada, Las Vegas",
                                                   "mainProductType": "Camper",
                                                  "allProductTypes": [

                                                                       "Extra",
                                                                       "Extra"
                                                                       ]
                                                    }
                                          }
                               "PAST": {
                                       "12061210": {
                                                    "startDate": "2012-05-05",
                                                    "destination": "Loire / Nivernais",
                                                      "mainProductType": "Boot",
                                                     "allProductTypes": [
                                                                        "Boot",
                                                                        "Extra"
                                                                        ]
                                                   }
                                       }      
                                  }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: the json posted is broken, it is (at least) missing the last } if the "PAST" element is really to be placed inside the "CURRENT" element

That said, the question is not really clear: you could get the element you want by index with the following expression:

```
$.payload.reservationLists.CURRENT[36735928]
```

if you know the name of the element you are trying to retrieve. If this is not what you meant, could you please elaborate on that?

Thank you, bye

Comment: My apologies. CURRENT and PAST are two separate. My target is how to get the node name so that I would get as "36735928" because I don't know the name of the element which is 36735928. I am not looking for the values for the node "36735928" which would give me startdate etc. Hope this would elaborate my question a bit.